# Опечатка в переводе в разделе Справка

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

Ошибка в меню [Справка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help).

> Как сообщить об агрессивное давление или запугивание

Предлагаемый текст.

> Как сообщить об агрессивном давлении или запугивании

[image: Опечатка в переводе текста]

Comment: Спасибо, что заметили. Заодно подправил опечатки в http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice